# Specifying return and input types in abstract class method

Tags: java

```
abstract class AbstractService<T> {
  private final T service;

  public AbstractService(T service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  startServiceCall() {} // how to specify types
```

I have an abstract class that should handle starting service calls (so that I can centralize logging, etc.).

And I have a child class:

```
public class ServiceWrapper extends AbstractService<ConcreteService>
```

I'm looking to have children services use `startServiceCall` like `startServiceCall(ConcreteService::getPage, bookId, pageNum)`

Is it possible to somehow specify type parameters in the abstract class to make `startServiceCall` in `AbstractService` use the `T service`?

I know one solution is I could have the `service` variable be not private and use `service::getPage`

Answer (score 2):

You could change your generic `T` with something like `<T extends AbstractService>`, so you could call any `AbstractService` method on `service`.

However, for your case, I don't think you're using generics as they were meant to be. You're much better off simply specifying abstract methods, such as `abstract Object getPage()` and calling that in your `startServiceCall` method. In this scenario, you wouldn't need the `service` field, as well, your concrete instance would be your service.